# Use a date field on a Rest Query In Apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, apexrest

I am trying to make a rest callout from one Salesforce org to another and I am using the following query in the rest end point

```
    DateTime sdt = DateTime.newInstance(startDate.year(), startDate.month(),startDate.day());
    String startDateFormat = sdt.format('yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00');
    System.debug('startDateFormat ::::: '+startDateFormat);
    request.setEndpoint('callout:'+namedCredential+'/services/data/v56.0/query?'+
                        'q=select+Id,+Name,+Reference_Code__c,+Patient_name_anonymized__c,'+
                        '+Primary_Treatment__r.Name,+Amount,+date_of_treatment__c,'+
                        '+Consultation_Booking_Date__c,+StageName,+'+
                        '+Brand__r.Imprint_Address__c+from+Opportunity+where+date_of_treatment__c+<+'+startDateFormat+'+AND+Brand__c+in+('+brandIdString+')');
```

Here, I keep on getting null pointer exception even after I have formatted the date.

Is it not permitted to filter via a date field in the rest query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I figured out that the primary issue is with the < special character in the query.

When we have a special character in the rest API query we need to encode it to UTF-8

which in this case would be %3E

so the request end point would look like the following :

```
       request.setEndpoint('callout:'+namedCredential+'/services/data/v56.0/query?'+
                        'q=select+Id,+Name,+Reference_Code__c,+Patient_name_anonymized__c,'+
                        '+Primary_Treatment__r.Name,+Amount,+date_of_treatment__c,'+
                        '+Consultation_Booking_Date__c,+StageName,'+
                        '+Brand__r.Imprint_Address__c+from+Opportunity'+
                        '+where+Test_Opportunity__c+=+false+AND'+
                        '+date_of_treatment__c+!=+null+AND'+
                        '+date_of_treatment__c+%3E=+'+startDateFormat+'+AND'+
                        '+date_of_treatment__c+%3C=+'+endDateFormat+'+AND'+
                        '+Brand__c+in+('+brandIdString+')');
```

Please note, this issue doesn't arise when we use workbench to test the endpoint. Also, = character in the query doesn't need to be encoded.

Comment: good catch!  See also [EncodingUtil.urlEncode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm?q=urlencode) which will do this for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `startDateFormat` to a valid SOQL date filter;

e.g., it should look like `2022-12-29` when inserted into the query string at point:

so ..

```
String startDateFormat = sdt.format('yyyy-MM-dd');


...from+Opportunity+where+date_of_treatment__c+!=+'+startDateFormat+'+AND+...
```

Comment: Actually I have tried that already, I should have updated my question. I have updated it now and I am still getting the same error. @cropredy

Comment: see updated answer